# How to apply function to each collection element in order to mutate it in Guava?

Tags: java, loops, guava

I'm using Guava 11 (because of java 5) for a year now but I don't seem to find a way of doing Groovy's each or Scala's foreach, that is to say, apply function to collection's elements that can mutate them and that returns the collection of mutated elements... All those methods on Iterables, Collections etc. practically can't do this. I don't want to use for loop. Maybe Iterables.all() could serve this purpose the best, but there is no way of doing stuff like :

```
Iterable result = Iterables.each(Iterables.filter(c, predicate), function);
```

Comment: so you want to transform each element in a collection using a function in guava?

Comment: no, I do want to modify element, transformation is Immutable thing, isn't it ?

Comment: what I meant is *have a new collection* where each element is obtained from some transformation of another collection?

Comment: I know, I would definitely use transformation for that. But sometimes I need mutability, it's not Scala :-)

Comment: can you then plz explain exactly what your questions is? Or even better provide an example?

Comment: Man I don't know what you can possibly see unclear here. If you have used Groovy you must have worked with iterable.each() many times and that's what I'm trying to find in Guava.

Comment: Maybe not everybody has worked with Groovy or Scala yet. You could improve your question if you would give an example and say what you did expect to happen, but what actually happens instead.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that Guava contains a method for this, because Java contains for-each loops to do it:

```
for(Element x : collection){
  mutate(x);
}
```

**Edit**: A more generic approach would be to encapsulate the for-each loop in a method and pass the mutation strategy as an argument to it:

```
interface Mutation<T> {
    void apply(T subject);
}

<T> Collection<? extends T> mutate(Collection<? extends T> input, Mutation<? super T> mutation) {
    for (T element : input) {
        mutation.apply(element);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Then why groovy and scala contain it if Java has for loops ? Because you can chain stuff, right ? Can you chain stuff with for loops ?

Comment: @Sloin Chaining for loops is easy (wait for it): write the first loop, then the second loop. Since you're modifying the content of the collection, there's no lazy transformation or filtering that needs chaining to actually perform the computation.

Comment: Great, write 3 loops, 3 private getMeSomething(arg) methods ... Perfectly off-putting imperative code... I'm asking this question so that I don't have to program imperatively and 2 guys come and say: do it imperatively...

Comment: @Sloin You said that you want to mutate elements of a collection. This in not a functional operation. Using it fluent-style (with chained method calls) and returning the same collection all the time doesn't make it less imperative.

Comment: Although I'm mutating the collection I'm also passing a Function that should be applied to its element, how is it not less imperative ?

Comment: @Sloin You are right, using a function-like object (I still wouldn't call it function as its side effects are important, not its return value) reduces the imperativeness of the code. I added another code snippet to the answer which may be more like what you expected.

Comment: @Sloin Java *is* an imperative language (and see [Guava's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) to see why you won't find each and every functional construct in Guava). When Java 8 finally gets out, you'll have a [`forEach()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Iterable.java) and the syntactic sugar of lambdas to help write a [`Consumer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/function/Consumer.java).

Comment: Yeah, but I'll get to work with Java 8 maybe in 2016 when customers might consider buying a licence for java 8 app servers.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer, the closest Guava collection method to Groovy's each method is Iterables.all. Predicate would be saying if either all members were modified or none at all. Although one cannot chain method calls, because Iterables.all() returns boolean.